# Evaluate $\int x(1-x)^n dx $ from 0 to 1

Tags: calculus, integration

Using integration by parts. And set $(1-x)=u$
$$\int (1-u)u^n -du$$ from 0 to 1

$$-1 [ (1-u)\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} + \int \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} du] $$ from 0 to 1

I keep getting $-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ the answer is without minus. Why?

Edit : authentic question [image]

Comment: What's the meaning of the second $-$ sign in $\int (1-u)u^n -du$?

Comment: $1-x=u$ so, dx = -du

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 x(1-x)^n dx $$
Substitute $u=1-x \implies  du=-dx$

Note that 
$$x=0 \implies u=1-x=1 $$

$$\text { And } x=1 \implies u=1-x=0$$
Be carefull with the bounds of the integral.
$$I=-\int_1^0 (1-u)u^n du=\int_0^1 (1-u)u^n du $$
$$I=\int_0^1 (u^n-u^{n+1}) du = \left | \dfrac {u^{n+1}}{n+1}-\dfrac {u^{n+2}}{n+2} \right |_0^1 $$
Finally:
$$I= \dfrac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}  $$

Comment: So, the minus sign is not changing the value? But the boundaries? Or what is the rule?

Comment: It changes both @Lifeforbetter change the bounds and the $dx=-du$ When $x=0$ you have $u=1-x=1$ When $x=1$ we have $u=1-x=0$ You see now ?

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's more clear now @Lifeforbetter

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x(1-x)^n \ \mathsf dx &= -\int_0^1 (1-u)u^n\ \mathsf du\\
&= -\int_0^1 u^n\ \mathsf du + \int_0^1 u^{n+1}\ \mathsf du\\
&= -\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2}\\
&= \frac{-(n+2)+(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&= -\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align}